# Identifying apache httpd "@@" command substitution in html file

Tags: apache

I'm trying to understand an index.html that has some kind of server side substitution going on. The web server is apache httpd. The commands look something like `@@json("title")` or

```
href="@@getDir("root")manage/manage.html"
```

or

```
@@jsonPush(api("SessionUser"))
```

It looks like these command substitutions can be placed anywhere HTML can go.

I'm assuming it's some custom CGI being called by the web server, but I'm not sure how to find documentation on this kind of substitution by Apache httpd.

Does anyone know what I'm looking at?